Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<ObjA__c>) from the type List<SObject>
I am trying to update two objects in single dml call but getting error as "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<ObjA__c>) from the type List".
Integer countA = [SELECT Count() FROM ObjA__c];
Integer countB = [SELECT Count() FROM ObjB__c];
Integer countAB = countA + countB;

List<ObjA__c> aList = new List<ObjA__c>();
List<ObjB__c> bList = new List<ObjB__c>();
for(ObjA__c a: [SELECT count__c FROM ObjA__c]){
    a.count__c = countAB;
    aList.add(a);
}
for(ObjB__c b: [SELECT count__c FROM ObjB__c]){
    b.count__c = countAB;
    bList.add(b);
}

List<sObject> records = new List<sObject>();
records.add(aList,);
records.add(bList);
update records;


Rolled back your edit because the original code that you had contains good context for the issue. It could help other people with similar problems.

.add() is for adding a single item, not a collection of items.
If you take a look at the documentation on the List class, you should see that there's also an .addAll() method, which does take a list (or a set).
